# Windows 7 to search a network drive

Tags: windows-7, search, indexing-service, network-share

Is there any way that I can have windows 7 clients be able to go to "start" and type in the name of a file that is located on a network drive? I have read that this is possible through indexing, but to get through the indexing steps I need to make files available offline. This network drive I speak of has about 2tb of files on it. How in the heck can I keep all this straight. I imagine there would be syncing errors everywhere if I were to make all of these files available offline. Not to mention not all files being current due to the large amounts of files. Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have [Windows Search 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/choose/windowssearch4.mspx) installed on the network servers that you want your windows 7 Clients to be able to search.

Comment: It would help if you could go into a lot more detail about the actual setup required on the server.  I have search for documentation about this in the past and didn't find anything good.

Comment: Take a look at this Microsoft Technet article for how to setup Windows Search 4.0: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461108(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_InstallWSandEnableFIleServices.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for this: [Windows Desktop Search: Add-in for Files on Microsoft Networks](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=f7e981d9-5a3b-4872-a07e-220761e27283&displaylang=en)

> This Protocol Handler indexes your shared network directories and FAT drive(s) allowing you to easily find your specific content. 
>   By downloading this Add-in, you will have the ability to search your shared network directories and FAT drive(s) via selection in your Windows Desktop Search Advanced Options.

Not available in x64 FYI.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, but still seemed like a pain to implement.
If you have Windows 7 index the share then you can search it.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itpronetworking/thread/afb904c1-1c61-4aae-b6b1-5cf525b9f8de